# Is it "Tú juegas como el" or "Tú juegas como él"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, gramática, definiciones

The sentence says "You play as him" but all of the choices have the last word as `el` instead of `él`. I believe "Tú juegas como él" to be the right choice, is that correct?

[image]

Comment: That's a typo in the app. Shit happens. I think also, that the question is quite localized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course the second one is the right way, `el` without the accent is an article and `él` with the accent is a pronoun, which in this case is the one that you should use.

**Update:**

```
el => article (the)
él => 3rd person pronoun (he/him)

tu => posesive (yours) 
tú => 2nd person pronoun (you)
```

So, to construct the sentence you're asking for, you will need both words to be pronouns to make real sense, so that would be :

*Tú juegas como él*  `You play as him.`

Remember `juegas` is the right conjugation of the verb `jugar` for the 2nd person present indicative, `juega` is for the 3rd person and `juego` is for the 1st.

Comment: If you only have those, yes, it should be the first, but as I say "él" has to be with the accent, is that Duolingo? that is wrong my friend, I am Spanish native, trust me, you were right, that app is wrong, notify it :)

Comment: Can you elaborate to explain why that is the correct answer?  Simply providing the correct answer on a multiple-choice question doesn't make for especially valuable content. :)

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice to improve the answer, look at the original Duolingo's sentece, is: "you play as him."

Comment: Fair enough... although I believe that's technically incorrect as well (even though people speak that way).

Comment: No sé porque hablamos entre nosotros en inglés si tu eres de Guadalajar y yo de Lima jajajaja. Bueno, quizás no sea lo óptimo pero así habla la gente y sobre todo esa es la pregunta que hicieron. Saludos.

Comment: "You play as him" would mean, taken literally, "You are playing the part of him." Like saying "You play as Captain Hook." Whereas "You play as he" has the meaning of "You play in the same manner in which he plays."  Both can be grammatically correct, but they have different meanings, and the latter is far more common, and almost certainly what the original context intended.

Answer (score 1):

Ooopsie, the app is wrong.
Tú juegas como él is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both, the first and the third answers, are correct (except for the `el` mistaken for `él` issue that you mention).

The first one `Tú juegas como él` is correct. It means `You play like he plays` or `You play the same way he plays`.

The third answer `Tú juega como él` is also correct because it is a mandatory sentence (imperative mood), meaning `You have to play like he does`.

Comment: Tendria que tener una coma la segunda para ser correcta. `Tú, juega como él`

Comment: Aunque esa "pausa" la hacemos cuando hablamos, el verbo `juega` concuerda en género y número con el sujeto `Tú`. Es cierto, que nunca se suele (o no se debe, quizá) utilizar así, creo que es totalmente válida.